# What does this notation ($Y = \mathrm dx$) in probability mean?

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

I'm reading this research article and can't seem to understand what this notation mean,
$P(T = i) = \int P(X>x)P(Y = \mathrm dx) $ where $T$, $X$, $Y$ are all obviously random variables. Irrespective of their particular definition, what would a RV equal to $\mathrm dx$ possibly mean ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe $\int f(x)P(X=dx)$ is meant to be a notation for $\int f(x)dF_X(x)$. The same integral can also be written as $\int f(x)P_X(dx)$ and that comes close to $\int f(x)P(X=dx)$.

Comment: Does $P(x\leq Y<x+dx)$ make more sense to you than $P(Y = dx)$?

Comment: You are integrating the function $x\mapsto P(X>x)$ with respect to the probability measure of $Y$.

Comment: Terrible notation. Even $P(Y\in dx)$ would be better, but only slightly so. Yes the authors mean $dP_Y(x)$.

Comment: Right, I do get some idea regarding it. Also noticed something else, since we are integrating $P(X>x)$, it must mean that this is not a constant rather a RV under the probability measure of Y ?

Comment: Read this as the Lebesgue integral $\int f\,\mathrm d\mu$, where $f(x)=P(X>x)$ and $\mu(A) = P_Y(A)$ is the measure defining the distribution of $Y$.

Comment: It is incorrect notation. It makes no sense to say a random variable is equal to $dx$. If $Y$ has PDF $f_Y(y)$ then they most likely mean $\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} P[X>x]f_Y(x)dx$.